# Getting ValueError: input tensor Tensor to TPUStrategy.run() has unknown rank, which is not allowed in Google Collab

Tags: tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory, tensor, tpu

I'm trying to train an RNN generative model using TPU in Google Colab. Full code of the notebook you can find [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1p4DNEuI2Agqm_GgDI1BO9B5ijBeLV9qT?usp=sharing). In brief, I take text files, chop them on sequences and targets, then made a tf.data.Dataset from the lists. Then prepare vocabulary, and create keras.TextVectorization object with pre-set vocabulary. Then prepare a one-hot dataset that should return sequences (features) as (60, 107) tensor and targets as (107,) tensor. Then I create a simple model with one LTSM layer inside

```
with strategy.scope():
```

and try to train the model in a cycle. Something like that:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tpu = tf.distribute.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver.connect()
strategy = tf.distribute.TPUStrategy(tpu)

#some code to make dataset (skipped)... and then

one_hot_dataset = dataset.map(lambda x, y: (tf.one_hot(text_vectorizer(x), 
                                                       depth=vocab_size, 
                                                       dtype='float32'), 
                                            tf.squeeze(tf.one_hot(text_vectorizer(y), 
                                                                  depth=vocab_size, 
                                                                  dtype='float32', 
                                                                  axis=1))))

batch_size = 1024 # I hope this can load a TPU sufficiently

one_hot_dataset = one_hot_dataset.batch(batch_size=batch_size,
                                        num_parallel_calls=4)

one_hot_dataset = one_hot_dataset.prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

# making a model

import keras
from keras import layers, Model

with strategy.scope():
    inputs = keras.Input(shape=(maxlen, vocab_size), dtype='float32')
    lstm_output = layers.LSTM(128)(inputs)
    output = layers.Dense(vocab_size, activation='softmax')(lstm_output)

    model = Model(inputs, output)

    model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=0.01),
                  loss='categorical_crossentropy')

# and finally

model.fit(one_hot_dataset, epochs=1)
```

Then I get an error:

```
ValueError: in user code:

    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1284, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1268, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))

    ValueError: input tensor Tensor("cond/Identity_8:0", dtype=float32) to TPUStrategy.run() has unknown rank, which is not allowed
```

that I even can't google.

The model trains normally on GPU (but too slowly). I have used the boiler code to fly with TPU earlier in a similar situation successfully. I am a bit suspicious about my dataset, but unfortunately can't understand the issue.

Comment: Can you make share dataset element shapes are set (except batch dimension) and printing `one_hot_dataset.element_spec` is correct.

```
def map_fn(x, y):
  first = tf.one_hot(text_vectorizer(x), depth=vocab_size, dtype='float32')
  first.set_shape((60, 107))
  second = tf.squeeze(tf.one_hot(text_vectorizer(y), depth=vocab_size,
                                 dtype='float32', axis=1))
  second.set_shape(my_shape)
  return (first, second)

one_hot_dataset = dataset.map(lambda x, y: map_fn(x, y))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you make share dataset element shapes are set (except batch dimension) and printing `one_hot_dataset.element_spec` is correct.

E.g.

```
def map_fn(x, y):
  first = tf.one_hot(text_vectorizer(x), depth=vocab_size, dtype='float32')
  first.set_shape((60, 107))
  second = tf.squeeze(tf.one_hot(text_vectorizer(y), depth=vocab_size,
                                 dtype='float32', axis=1))
  second.set_shape(my_shape)
  return (first, second)

one_hot_dataset = dataset.map(map_fn)
```

Comment: Moving one-hot vectorizing logic from lambda in `dataset.map(...)` to a dedicated function and explicitly setting shapes of output tensors helped. Thank you. It would be great to know why that works; however, it is undoubtedly a secondary question...